# How to save the previous input in multi-form scenario?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

This is what i want to do: I want to save the input of all the forms and not just one, because the code below will save the input of lets say the second form but when i go to the 1st form, select something from the values and clik on the submit button it will remember now the 1st form input and forget the second form input. I want a solution that will help me to keep the previous values of other forms till the moment i decide to change it with another selected value.
Some of you will say just put them in one form and with one submit button and the problem will be solved but this is not the solution i am trying to find because i am working in a project and i need a solution without merging them together.

```
<?php
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (!empty($_POST['action']))):

    if (isset($_POST['semester1'])) { $semester1 = $_POST['semester1']; }
    if (isset($_POST['semester2'])) { $semester2 = $_POST['semester2']; }
    if (isset($_POST['semester3'])) { $semester3 = $_POST['semester3']; }
    if (isset($_POST['semester4'])) { $semester4 = $_POST['semester4']; }
    if (isset($_POST['semester5'])) { $semester5 = $_POST['semester5']; }
    if (isset($_POST['semester6'])) { $semester6 = $_POST['semester6']; }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action='' method='POST' name="theform"><!--==========Start of the Form========-->

Semester: <select class="form-control" name="semester1">
                <option><?php if (isset($semester1)) { echo $semester1; } ?></option>
                              <option>Fall</option>
                              <option>Spring</option>
                              <option>Summer</option>  
                            </select>
<button type="submit" value="Submit"  name="action">Submit The Data</button>
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action='' method='POST' name="theform"><!--==========Start of the Form========-->

Semester: <select class="form-control" name="semester2">
                <option><?php if (isset($semester2)) { echo $semester2; } ?></option>
                              <option>Fall</option>
                              <option>Spring</option>
                              <option>Summer</option>  
                            </select>
<button type="submit" value="Submit"  name="action">Submit The Data</button>
</form>


<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action='' method='POST' name="theform"><!--==========Start of the Form========-->

Semester: <select class="form-control" name="semester3">
                <option><?php if (isset($semester3)) { echo $semester3; } ?></option>
                              <option>Fall</option>
                              <option>Spring</option>
                              <option>Summer</option>  
                            </select>
<button type="submit" value="Submit"  name="action">Submit The Data</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Two options :1. Use only one form and show/hide input fields with the use of jquery ..2: Use saperate tables in the database for each form and you can retrive data by using JOINS

Comment: the project is bigger than that i just wrote some code to get the idea of my question i cant use one form and i have eleminated that option in my description :P

Comment: @Vanquisher then use the second option(see edited comment)

Comment: Then store the input in sessions and output the session values if they are set

Comment: for example what do you suggest i mean some code sample?

Answer (score 1):

It seems i found a solution and it seems to work i need to thank  #DarkBee for the session idea.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (!empty($_POST['action']))):

    if (isset($_POST['semester1'])) { $_SESSION['1'] = $_POST['semester1']; }else{$_SESSION['1'];}
    if (isset($_POST['semester2'])) { $_SESSION['2'] = $_POST['semester2']; }else{$_SESSION['2'];}
    if (isset($_POST['semester3'])) { $_SESSION['3'] = $_POST['semester3']; }else{$_SESSION['3'];}
    if (isset($_POST['semester4'])) { $semester4 = $_POST['semester4']; }
    if (isset($_POST['semester5'])) { $semester5 = $_POST['semester5']; }
    if (isset($_POST['semester6'])) { $semester6 = $_POST['semester6']; }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action='' method='POST' name="theform"><!--==========Start of the Form========-->

Semester: <select class="form-control" name="semester1">
                <option><?php if (isset($_SESSION['1'])) { echo $_SESSION['1']; } ?></option>
                              <option>Fall</option>
                              <option>Spring</option>
                              <option>Summer</option>  
                            </select>
<button type="submit" value="Submit"  name="action">Submit The Data</button>
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action='' method='POST' name="theform"><!--==========Start of the Form========-->

Semester: <select class="form-control" name="semester2">
                <option><?php if (isset($_SESSION['2'])) { echo $_SESSION['2']; } ?></option>
                              <option>Fall</option>
                              <option>Spring</option>
                              <option>Summer</option>  
                            </select>
<button type="submit" value="Submit"  name="action">Submit The Data</button>
</form>


<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action='' method='POST' name="theform"><!--==========Start of the Form========-->

Semester: <select class="form-control" name="semester3">
                <option><?php if (isset($_SESSION['3'])) { echo $_SESSION['3']; } ?></option>
                              <option>Fall</option>
                              <option>Spring</option>
                              <option>Summer</option>  
                            </select>
<button type="submit" value="Submit"  name="action">Submit The Data</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example for session based storing of your form data.
Do note using @ to supress errors/notices is not done

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['txt_name'])) $_SESSION['txt_name'] = [];

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    ##-- cause i'm lazy 
    foreach($_POST['txt_name'] as $key => $value) {
        $_SESSION['txt_name'][$key] = $value;
    }
}   
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo '<form name="form'.$i.'" id="form'.$i.'" action="#form'.$i.'" method="POST">';
    echo '<label for="txt_name'.$i.'">Name'.$i.'</label>';
    echo '<input type="text" id="txt_name'.$i.'" name="txt_name['.$i.']" value="'.@$_SESSION['txt_name'][$i].'">';
    echo '<button type="submit">Submit</button>';
    echo '</form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: i didnt try this but you gave me the idea to use the sessions I totally forgot about them thx DarkBee.